# How to extract MPMediaItemCollection to NSData in AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, avplayer, mpmediapickercontroller

I  want to play device songs using avplayer in my app. In NSLog i m getting array value    ===>    " 18023427656013653237",
        " 15946441828903552798",
        " 10791915036547881152",
        " 17986655796364263078"
// Now i want to  what are these values .....

I have tried this.....

```
-(IBAction)SelectSongs:(id)sender
{

MPMediaPickerController *picker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeAny];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsPickingMultipleItems =YES;
picker.prompt = @"Select songs from the list";

[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:^(void) {}];
}

-(void) mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *) mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:  (MPMediaItemCollection *) mediaItemCollection
{


if (mediaItemCollection)
{
    NSMutableArray *medialibraryArray;
    medialibraryArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [medialibraryArray addObject:mediaItemCollection.items];// Modified
    NSLog(@"%@=========>",medialibraryArray);


}
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(void) {}];}

-(void) mediaPickerDidCancel: (MPMediaPickerController *) mediaPicker
{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(void) {}];
}


// Thanks in Advance
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(void) mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *) mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:  (MPMediaItemCollection *) mediaItemCollection
{


    if (mediaItemCollection)
    {
        NSArray *items = [mediaItemCollection items];
        for( int n=0; n < items.count; n++ )    {
            MPMediaItem *mediaItem = [items objectAtIndex:n];
            NSLog(@"%@=========>",[mediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle]);
        }

        MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];
        [musicPlayer setQueueWithItemCollection: mediaItemCollection];
        NSLog(@"==>%@",musicPlayer);


    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(void) {}];
}
```

You're going to get all the songs in your library with this so the printout might take a while! Read up on MPMediaItem Class Reference and media queries to see how to get a subset of your entire music library.

Comment: Thanks a lot...for ur valuable suggestion